# Attribute bands name displaying double time?

Tags: magento-1.9, attributes

I have created attribute BANDS. **Apothic** bands option is not there in my attribute list but still its showing double time.
[image]

[image]

Comment: you need to provide more information, If you need solution to you problem

Comment: I have created attribute called "BRAND".  i have not added the option name called "Apothic" but still its displaying in  front end double time.

Comment: the type of attribute is ? have you check the product on admin if the attribute vallue is assigned ?

Comment: dropdown attribute. I am displaying all the brand name in separate page. Please check my issue one again.i have attached the screenshot

Comment: are you sure there is no duplicate entry in list of brands under the attribute, check it carefully, there may be chances that the list is not sorted and you end-up adding the the brand twice unknowingly. **Tip**. Use Browser Search option to search on the page.

Comment: check your attribute in admin panel, whether there have any repeated ?

Comment: No there is no brand "Apothic" in my admin dropdown also.